# Matlab webread fails to download data from World Databank

Tags: xml, matlab, api

I've tried to download economic data from the World Databank using this command:

```
DATA = webread('http://api.worldbank.org/countries/all/indicators/NY.GDP.MKTP.CD');
```

Instead of getting the data, I get a chunk of XML code.

What should I do?

Here is the databank documentation:

https://datahelpdesk.worldbank.org/knowledgebase/articles/898599-api-indicator-queries

And here is the XML chunk I get:

```
﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wb:indicators page="1" pages="1" per_page="50" total="1" 
xmlns:wb="http://www.worldbank.org">
  <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">
    <wb:name>GDP (current US$)</wb:name>
    <wb:source id="2">World Development Indicators</wb:source>
    <wb:sourceNote>GDP at purchaser's prices is the sum of gross value added by all resident producers in the economy plus any product taxes and minus any subsidies not included in the value of the products. It is calculated without making deductions for depreciation of fabricated assets or for depletion and degradation of natural resources. Data are in current U.S. dollars. Dollar figures for GDP are converted from domestic currencies using single year official exchange rates. For a few countries where the official exchange rate does not reflect the rate effectively applied to actual foreign exchange transactions, an alternative conversion factor is used.</wb:sourceNote>
    <wb:sourceOrganization>World Bank national accounts data, and OECD National Accounts data files.</wb:sourceOrganization>
    <wb:topics>
      <wb:topic id="3">Economy &amp; Growth</wb:topic>
    </wb:topics>
  </wb:indicator>
</wb:indicators>
```

Help much appreciated!

Comment: Doesn't the XML code contain the data you want?

Comment: The documentation you link to clearly shows that XML is expected to be returned.  You'll need to use an XML parser to extract the fields you need, or try to use something like `xmlread` to get the object model.

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It perfectly works for me. When I execute your `webread` API query, this is what I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <wb:data page="1" pages="301" per_page="50" total="15048" xmlns:wb="http://www.worldbank.org">
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>2009</wb:date>
     <wb:value>1795472295052.32</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>2008</wb:date>
     <wb:value>2077706582271.06</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>2007</wb:date>
     <wb:value>1637573196970.62</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>2006</wb:date>
     <wb:value>1404113530800.68</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>2005</wb:date>
     <wb:value>1184661549595.13</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>2004</wb:date>
     <wb:value>963862340520.581</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>2003</wb:date>
     <wb:value>823110541431.167</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>2002</wb:date>
     <wb:value>729051715403.984</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>2001</wb:date>
     <wb:value>723282816382.445</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>2000</wb:date>
     <wb:value>735025140336.255</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1999</wb:date>
     <wb:value>643889670873.196</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1998</wb:date>
     <wb:value>591525594021.399</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1997</wb:date>
     <wb:value>613279452474.103</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1996</wb:date>
     <wb:value>578231297763.478</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1995</wb:date>
     <wb:value>523759898288.293</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1994</wb:date>
     <wb:value>487526906280.526</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1993</wb:date>
     <wb:value>476513630630.268</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1992</wb:date>
     <wb:value>471163515480.256</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1991</wb:date>
     <wb:value>439779177858.364</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1990</wb:date>
     <wb:value>446877161735.167</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1989</wb:date>
     <wb:value>322325140494.687</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1988</wb:date>
     <wb:value>307503035642.479</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1987</wb:date>
     <wb:value>312681678329.895</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1986</wb:date>
     <wb:value>289029150639.408</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1985</wb:date>
     <wb:value>303893618415.506</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1984</wb:date>
     <wb:value>307940771858.505</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1983</wb:date>
     <wb:value>303962539723.043</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1982</wb:date>
     <wb:value>324328753765.261</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1981</wb:date>
     <wb:value>348592795413.075</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1980</wb:date>
     <wb:value>338177454717.499</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1979</wb:date>
     <wb:value>248646206366.973</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1978</wb:date>
     <wb:value>183555544342.167</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1977</wb:date>
     <wb:value>167308327683.573</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1976</wb:date>
     <wb:value>144846175400.471</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1975</wb:date>
     <wb:value>116337021938.327</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1974</wb:date>
     <wb:value>105145803084.364</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1973</wb:date>
     <wb:value>55018394945.576</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1972</wb:date>
     <wb:value>43316056615.451</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1971</wb:date>
     <wb:value>36426909888.3884</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1970</wb:date>
     <wb:value>31385499664.0635</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1969</wb:date>
     <wb:value>28434203615.4795</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1968</wb:date>
     <wb:value>25760683041.0826</wb:value>
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1967</wb:date>
     <wb:value />
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1966</wb:date>
     <wb:value />
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1965</wb:date>
     <wb:value />
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1964</wb:date>
     <wb:value />
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1963</wb:date>
     <wb:value />
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1962</wb:date>
     <wb:value />
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1961</wb:date>
     <wb:value />
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
   <wb:data>
     <wb:indicator id="NY.GDP.MKTP.CD">GDP (current US$)</wb:indicator>
     <wb:country id="1A">Arab World</wb:country>
     <wb:date>1960</wb:date>
     <wb:value />
     <wb:decimal>0</wb:decimal>
   </wb:data>
 </wb:data>
```

Once it is read, anyway, you have to make sanitize your data and then parse it as `XML`. Hence:

```
res = webread('http://api.worldbank.org/countries/all/indicators/NY.GDP.MKTP.CD');
res = unicode2native(res);
res = native2unicode(res,'UTF-8');

% If the xmlread function throws a SAXParseException in the form of "content is not allowed in prolog", use the following like of code to get rid of the BOM garbage at the beginning of the string, before the XML declaration. Otherwise, just comment this and proceed.
res = res(2:end);

iobj = java.io.StringBufferInputStream(res);
tobj = xmlread(iobj);
```

You decode the string you receive as bytes, then you re-encode it into `UTF-8` to make sure you are using the proper encoding (the `XML` parser here wants `UTF-8` encoded strings). If `BOM` garbage at the beginning of the string makes your function fail, get rid of it. Once you have your `XML` tree, just iterate its nodes and pick the data you need.